# Center element contents when they arranged vertically

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a responsive website. I want that when the horizontal size is decreased to a point when these divs are no longer on the same line, that the contents are centered on the page. I could set `@media (max-width:` and set it to an arbitrary number, but the width of these divs may change because of changing content.

HTML:

```
<div class="cool">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div>
<div class="story">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cool {
    float: left;
}
.story {
    float: right;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a0vk35yc/1/

Update: Better demo.

Comment: When the width of the div's changes based on the content, you need to "calculate" the width with JavaScript and change your media query dynamically based on the output of the JavaScript.

Comment: Either as @ThomasBormans said or use percentages

Comment: @dwhite.me How would you use percentages for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, the elements on the page must have some kind of minimum content width otherwise they'd always sit side-by-side and could shrink down to any pixel width.

This minimum width might not be known until the page flow is complete, so you need to do it in a `document.onLoad` Javascript handler. Calculate `left_min_width` and `right_min_width` and set up a media query with a breakpoint at `(left_min_width+right_min_width)px`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a minimal understanding of JS and was hoping this wouldn't require it. I'm learning JS now, but I'll just use `@media` until then.